# Allow only $ref type in JSON array

Tags: json, json.net, jsonschema

I have the following schema, in which the array `values` shall only accept objects of type `value`. I am using [Newtonsoft.Json v11.0.2](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json) for validation.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "http://some.thing/json",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "value": {
      "$id": "/definitions/value",
      "required": ["a", "b", "c"],
      "properties": {
        "a": {
          "$id": "/properties/value/a",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "b": {
          "$id": "/properties/value/b",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "c": {
          "$id": "/properties/value/c",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": ["values"],
  "properties": {
    "values": {
      "$id": "/properties/values",
      "type": "array",
      "items":
      {
        "$id": "/properties/values/item",
        "$ref": "/definitions/value"
      },
      "uniqueItems": true
    }
  }
}
```

This works as it will not validate something like

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "a": "a2",
      "b": "b2"
    }
  ]
}
```

but does validate

```
{
  "values": [
    {
      "a": "a2",
      "b": "b2",
      "c": "c3"
    },
    "string"
  ]
}
```

which it should not.

How can I force that only `value`s can be in the array? `"additionalItems": false` limits the amount of items and `"additionalProperties": false` within "items" seemingly does nothing, so these are also not what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to validate the valid items of the values array, and `"additionalProperties": false` within your items defintinition would only effect an object.

In stead, you need to add `"type": "object"` to your value definition...

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
  "$id": "http://some.thing/json",
  "type": "object",
  "definitions": {
    "value": {
      "$id": "/definitions/value",
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "a": {
          "$id": "/properties/value/a",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "b": {
          "$id": "/properties/value/b",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "c": {
          "$id": "/properties/value/c",
          "type": "string"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "required": [
    "values"
  ],
  "properties": {
    "values": {
      "$id": "/properties/values",
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "$ref": "/definitions/value"
      }
    },
    "uniqueItems": true
  }
}
```